# Installing service with command script fails in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-services, batch-file, uac

I need to automate the installation of a service so i wrote a simple command script. My command script copies two executables and runs an install command on the service executable. It works fine in XP but fails to install in windows7.


The contents of setup.cmd:

```
xcopy udpclient_service.exe C:\Services 
xcopy udpclient_userapp.exe C:\Services

C:\Services\udpclient_service.exe install
```

The executables get copied but the install command fails. No idea why. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run your script elevated - either right-click, run as administrator, or launch it from a command prompt that you ran elevated. Installing a service is an administrative task - you need to indicate in advance that you plan to use your powers.

Comment: Your completely right. However, When run as administrator the xcopy commands don't work. I have to run the script once and then again as admin for the install to work. Strange.

Comment: probably a different current directory. Add an echo to diagnose.

Comment: Works fine now. Just added "set OLDDIR=%CD%". Is there a way run this script without a user having to verify admin rights?

Comment: Whenever you want to elevate, someone needs to consent. The only things that are exempted are things that need elevation to install, like services. Someone sometime has to say it's ok.